# Azure ARM template accessing storage key

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am trying to access azure OMS ID, primary key for the same OMS, storage account key, following is the command where I want to pass these details for installation in this format `sh ./install-master.sh <OMS ID> <OMS Key> <Storage Account Name> <Storage Account Key>`

```
"protectedSettings": {
      "commandToExecute": "[concat('sh ./install-master.sh ',reference(resourceId(parameters('omsResourceGroup'),'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/', parameters('omsWorkspace')), '2015-11-01-preview').customerId,' ',listKeys(resourceId(parameters('omsResourceGroup'),'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/', parameters('omsWorkspace')), '2015-11-01-preview').primarySharedKey,' ',parameters('scriptStorageAccount'),' ',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts',parameters('scriptStorageAccount')),providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value))]"
     }
```

I am getting following error message

```
InvalidTemplate: Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'node1/CustomInstall' at line '265' and column '10' is not valid: Unable to parse language expression 'concat('sh ./nifi-install-master.sh ',reference(resourceId(parameters('omsResourceGroup'),'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/', parameters('omsWorkspace')), '2015-11-01-preview').customerId,' ',listKeys(resourceId(parameters('omsResourceGroup'),'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/', parameters('omsWorkspace')), '2015-11-01-preview').primarySharedKey,' ',parameters('scriptStorageAccount'),' ',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts',parameters('scriptStorageAccount')),providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value))': expected token 'EndOfData' and actual 'RightParenthesis'.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.'.
```

Is there any other way I can test the reference I am passing in the ARM ?

Answer (score 1):

The error kinda hints you have got 1 extra right parenthesis:

```
xxx.keys[0].value))]" <<< remove one in the end
```